# Why is the code showing only `1 2`?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I want to test my program and to test it I just convert integers of one ListNode to String and concatenate those conversions. For example, if I have:

```
ListNode object1;
object1 = new ListNode(2);
object1 = new ListNode(4);
object1 = new ListNode(3);
```

the output from the addTwoNumbers() should be "243" (The goal of the method is different, I just want to test it) but it's giving me "1 2". And Eclipse won't also run debugger in this program and don't know why.

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }

public String addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    String l1Digits = "";
    String l2Digits = "";

    while(l1 != null) {
        l1Digits += Integer.toString(l1.val) + "";
        l1 = l1.next;
    }

    while(l2 != null) {
        l2Digits += Integer.toString(l2.val) + "";
        l2 = l2.next;
    }
    return l1Digits;
}


class Tester {

  public void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode object1;
    object1 = new ListNode(2);
    object1 = new ListNode(4);
    object1 = new ListNode(3);

    ListNode object2;
    object2 = new ListNode(5);
    object2 = new ListNode(6);
    object2 = new ListNode(4);

    System.out.println(addTwoNumbers(object1, object2));

  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

> ```
> ListNode object1;
> object1 = new ListNode(2);
> object1 = new ListNode(4);
> object1 = new ListNode(3);
>
> ListNode object2;
> object2 = new ListNode(5);
> object2 = new ListNode(6);
> object2 = new ListNode(4);
> ```

It seems you really meant this:

```
ListNode object1;
object1 = new ListNode(2);
object1.next = new ListNode(4);
object1.next.next = new ListNode(3);

ListNode object2;
object2 = new ListNode(5);
object2.next = new ListNode(6);
object2.next.next = new ListNode(4);
```

In the original code, you overwrite the value of `object1` and `object2`.
This is equivalent to your original code and certainly not what you wanted:

```
ListNode object1 = new ListNode(3);
ListNode object2 = new ListNode(4);
```

To create longer lists, this can get tedious.
You can create a helper method to make that easier, for example:

```
ListNode createList(int...values) {
    if (values.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    ListNode head = new ListNode(values[0]);
    ListNode node = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
        node.next = new ListNode(values[i]);
        node = node.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

This will allow you to replace the first code at the top with this:

```
ListNode object1 = createList(2, 4, 3);
ListNode object2 = createList(5, 6, 4);
```

Btw there are other issues too in your program.
In `addTwoNumbers` you assign to `l2Digits` but never access it.
It seems completely unused and pointless.
The method simply concatenates the values in the first list and returns it,
so it's not doing anything its name suggests.

Comment: What if i have a bigger number, how should I run the loop ?? @janos

Comment: Still giving `1 2` even after changing to what you suggested, @janos

Comment: Your original code prints `3`. After the changes I suggested it prints `243`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you assign a new value to `object1`, you're implicitly removing all the previously assigned. You should append the nodes to the back to the LinkNode instead by assigning the `next` field.

You should have a method like `addToTail` inside ListNode.

```
public class ListNode {

    // ... all the fields and methods you already have

    public void addToTail(ListNode newNode) {
        if (this == null) {
            this = newNode;
            return;
        }
        ListNode tmp = this;
        // traverse to the tail node
        while(tmp.next) { tmp = tmp.next; }
        tmp.next = newNode;
        return;
    }
}

ListNode object1;
object1.addToTail(new ListNode(2)); // (2)
object1.addToTail(new ListNode(4)); // (2) -> (4)
object1.addToTail(new ListNode(3)); // (2) -> (4) -> (3) .. and so on
```